# How can I hack my intercom system to buzz people in remotely?

Tags: arduino-uno

How would you go about activating this button remotely?

This board is from the intercom in my apartment. The button when pressed unlocks the building door. I've just ordered the MKR IoT bundle (https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-iot-mkr1000-bundle). My plan is to learn the basics and figure out how to activate this button remotely.

[image]

Comment: Check, how the button is connected on the board, if you can. Check, if there is any electrical load is connected to it (which would need a specific current to flow at minimum). Check, which voltage the system and especially the microcontroller use. Then maybe you can use a transistor (or relay for heavy load) to bridge the button depending on a voltage, that can be controlled by your MKR (note that it runs on 3.3V). Do your research and then edit your question to more precisely state the problem.

Comment: Agreed.  Please take the http://www.arduino.stackexchange.com/Tour to see how to format a question.  You are welcome here but we'll need more information in order to be able to help.

Comment: use a relay module; it's the safest simplest most compatible way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 possible solutions:

1. Connect the 2 contact for the button to a relay and control that relay from the arduino ([example](https://learn.adafruit.com/experimenters-guide-for-metro?view=all#circ11-intro)) But the kit you have doesn't include a relay.
2. Use a transistor to trigger the switch -- I would not recommend this option as your first project.  It would be easy to damage the intercom and/or your arduino.
3. Use the servo in the kit to physically press the button.  You will need to figure out the mechanical linkages but you don't need to attach wires to the intercom.

For a beginner project I would probably go with the third option.

Comment: 4. Use an optocoupler. It isolates the Arduino, just like the relay does, but doesn’t require as much power as the relay (and doesn’t make any noise).